# Calculatng the <Target> of a <PolicySet> or <Policy>

Tags: authorization, xacml

I am trying to understand what the XACML [specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959496) mean by how a `<target>` elements can be calculated from the `<Target>` elements of the `<PolicySet>`, `<Policy>` and `<Rule>` elements that it contains. Section 3.3.2.1 gives the following explanation:

> ...there are two logical methods that might be used.  In one method, the `<Target>` element of the outer `<PolicySet>` or `<Policy>` (the "outer component") is calculated as the union of all the `<Target>` elements of the referenced `<PolicySet>`, `<Policy>` or `<Rule>` elements (the "inner components").
>   In another method, the `<Target>` element of the outer component is calculated as the intersection of all the `<Target>` elements of the inner components.
>   The results of evaluation in each case will be very different: in the first case, the `<Target>` element of the outer component makes it applicable to any decision request that matches the `<Target>` element of at least one inner component; in the second case, the `<Target>` element of the outer component makes it applicable only to decision requests that match the `<Target>` elements of every inner component.

I do understand why this is done, clearly to be able to select the proper Policy or PolictSet to evaluate, but I have no idea how this can be accomplished. I did look at [Sun's XACML](http://sunxacml.sourceforge.net/) and [AT&T XACML 3.0](https://github.com/att/XACML) implementations, but can't find any code samples to illustrate how this is done.

So, my question is, can somebody explain in detail how this calculation is to be done or refer to a (academic) paper or code that ahows this type of calculation?  Did I miss something in the Sun and AT&T code base?